# Can a dog tell when their owner is unhappy?

Tags: dogs, behavior

If you've read my previous questions, or viewed my profile (Newly updated!), you may already be aware that I have a dog. I've been noticing that my dog is starting to seem like he knows when something is not right or making me or my roommates unhappy. Good example: My tangelos are starting to bloom their January flowers to fertilize before being harvested in February or March, so there's pollen EVERYWHERE and so right now as I type this, I am a stuffed up, snotty, coughing mess. Gizmo keeps acting like he knows something is wrong. Is this a coincidence? Or can a dog actually tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All living beings have *emotions*, and have the ability to understand emotions. It was even proven that even plants can recognize the people who hurt or love them.

On the other side, different beings show different levels of *empathy* or *support*. Dogs tend to be more on the supportive side. Cats tend to be more on the I-do-not-give-a-dime side. People can be on all sides of the spectrum, there is no rule about them.